# adding key values inside of an array of hashes using .each

Tags: ruby, function, methods, each

I'm wondering what the easiest method for adding 'string' values in an array of hashes using an each statement?

```
lost_boys = [
    {name: 'Tootles', age: '11'},
    {name: 'Nibs', age: '9'},
    {name: 'Slightly', age: '10'},
    {name: 'Curly', age: '8'},
    {name: 'The Twins', age: '9'}
  ]
  a = []
lost_boys.each do |ages|
    a = ages[:age].to_i
    
    puts a    
end
```

Comment: Not sure I understand but maybe you are looking for `lost_boys.sum {|boy| boy[:age].to_i}`?

Comment: I expect you are looking for `lost_boys.each { |ages| a << ages[:age].to_i }; puts a` (or, equivalently, `...a.push(ages[:age].to_i )...`). Better: `a = lost_boys.map { |ages| ages[:age].to_i } #=> [11, 9, 10, 8, 9]`.